# What is the sum of the series where $a_n = an^{log_b(n)}$

Tags: summation

I'm struggling with a growth model and finding a formula to describe the growth.

I've managed to figure out $a_n = an^{log_b(n)}$ but now need to find a formula for the sum of the series $S_n = f(n)$

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The series is divergent. Do you mean a sum from $n=1$ to $n=N$?

Comment: Yes, thank you!

Comment: I think I should be able to use Stirling's approximation in some way, but haven't managed to reach something with $log(n!)$

Comment: So you are looking for $$S_n=a\,\sum^n_{k=1}e^{\ln^2k/\ln b}$$ essentially, is that correct? There is certainly no closed expression, but an approximation should be possible.